# Delete all folders inside a folder except one with specific name

Tags: linux, find, delete

I need to delete all folders inside a folder using a daily script.  The folder for that day needs to be left.

Folder 'myfolder' has 3 sub folder: 'test1', 'test2' and 'test3'
I need to delete all except 'test2'.

I am trying to match exact name here:

```
find /home/myfolder -type d ! -name 'test2' | xargs rm -rf
```

OR

```
find /home/myfolder -type d ! -name 'test2' -delete
```

This command always tries to delete the main folder 'myfolder' also !
Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: In Unix and Linux, we call these "directories", not "folders".

Comment: Depending on your shell, you may need to quote that `!` operator: `\!` or `'!'`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This will delete all folders inside `./myfolder` except that `./myfolder/test2` and all its contents will be preserved:

```
find ./myfolder -mindepth 1 ! -regex '^./myfolder/test2\(/.*\)?' -delete
```

#### How it works

- `find` starts a find command.
- `./myfolder` tells find to start with the directory `./myfolder` and its contents.
- `-mindepth 1`  not to match `./myfolder` itself, just the files and directories under it.
- `! -regex '^./myfolder/test2\(/.*\)?'`  tells find to exclude (`!`) any file or directory matching the regular expression `^./myfolder/test2\(/.*\)?`.  `^` matches the start of the path name.  The expression  `(/.*\)?` matches either (a) a slash followed by anything or (b) nothing at all.
- `-delete`  tells find to delete the matching (that is, non-excluded) files.

#### Example

Consider a directory structure that looks like;

```
$ find ./myfolder
./myfolder
./myfolder/test1
./myfolder/test1/dir1
./myfolder/test1/dir1/test2
./myfolder/test1/dir1/test2/file4
./myfolder/test1/file1
./myfolder/test3
./myfolder/test3/file3
./myfolder/test2
./myfolder/test2/file2
./myfolder/test2/dir2
```

We can run the find command (without `-delete`) to see what it matches:

```
$ find ./myfolder -mindepth 1 ! -regex '^./myfolder/test2\(/.*\)?'
./myfolder/test1
./myfolder/test1/dir1
./myfolder/test1/dir1/test2
./myfolder/test1/dir1/test2/file4
./myfolder/test1/file1
./myfolder/test3
./myfolder/test3/file3
```

We can verify that this worked by looking at the files which remain:

```
$ find ./myfolder
./myfolder
./myfolder/test2
./myfolder/test2/file2
./myfolder/test2/dir2
```

Comment: Alternative to `-prune` to leave `test2/*/` subdirectories alone: return to `rm -r` and add `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: @Isaac OK.  Done.  (Also, +1 for your excellent answer.)

Comment: Excellent work!, but sorry: that will remove all **files** inside `./myfolder`. You need a missing (IMvhO) `-type d` for **only directories**.

Comment: Ok, this should work as you want: `find ./myfolder -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -regex '^./myfolder/test2\(/.*\)?'`

Answer (score 19):

[Using bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -r myfolder/!(test2)/
```

Example:

```
$ tree myfolder/
myfolder/
├── test1
│   └── file1
├── test2
│   └── file2
└── test3
    └── file3

$ echo rm -r myfolder/!(test2)
rm -r myfolder/test1 myfolder/test3
$ rm -r myfolder/!(test2)
$ tree myfolder/
myfolder/
└── test2
    └── file2

1 directory, 1 file
```

Comment: awesome, 20 years using bash I never wondered rm could get some sort of regex!

Answer (score 13):

## tl;dr

```
find ./myfolder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name test2 \
     -exec echo rm -rf '{}' \;
```

Remove echo if satisfied with the list of files.

---

Using `-mindepth 1` will ensure that the **top** directory is not selected.

```
$ find ./myfolder -mindepth 1 -type d
./myfolder/test2
./myfolder/test2/one
./myfolder/test2/two
./myfolder/test
./myfolder/test/a1
./myfolder/test/a1/a2
./myfolder/test/a1/a2/a3
```

But a `-not -name test2` will **not** avoid subdirs inside `test2`:

```
$ find ./myfolder -mindepth 1 -type d -not -name 'test2'
./myfolder/test2/one
./myfolder/test2/two
./myfolder/test
./myfolder/test/a1
./myfolder/test/a1/a2
./myfolder/test/a1/a2/a3
```

To do that, you need something like prune:

```
$ find ./myfolder -mindepth 1 -name test2 -prune -o -type d -print
./myfolder/test
./myfolder/test/a1
./myfolder/test/a1/a2
./myfolder/test/a1/a2/a3
```

**But** do not use `delete`, as it implies `depth` and that will start erasing from the longest path:

```
$ find ./myfolder -depth -mindepth 1 -name test2 -prune -o -type d -print
./myfolder/test/a1/a2/a3
./myfolder/test/a1/a2
./myfolder/test/a1
./myfolder/test
```

Either use `rm -rf` (remove the `echo` if you want to actually erase):

```
$ find ./myfolder -mindepth 1 -name test2 -prune -o -type d -exec echo rm -rf '{}' \;
rm -rf ./myfolder/test
rm -rf ./myfolder/test/a1
rm -rf ./myfolder/test/a1/a2
rm -rf ./myfolder/test/a1/a2/a3
```

Or, **also** use `maxdepth` if all you need is to delete directories (and everything inside) (remove the `echo` to actually erase):

```
$ find ./myfolder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name test2 -exec echo rm -rf '{}' \;
rm -rf ./myfolder/test
```

A `-delete` will still fail if the directory is not empty:

```
$ find ./myfolder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name test2 -delete
find: cannot delete ‘./myfolder/test’: Directory not empty
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using zsh, then you could:

```
setopt extended_glob # if you don't have it enabled

rm -rf myfolder/^test2(/)
```

`^foo` is a glob meaning everything except `foo`, and `(/)` is a glob qualifier that says that the glob should only match directories.

Answer (score 3):

If the requirement is only for level one (not more than depth 1) as mentioned in the question, here is another easy option:

```
ls myfolder/ | grep -v "test2" | xargs rm -r
```

Details:

- `ls myfolder/` lists all folders and files inside `myfolder/` directory
- `grep -v "test2"` matches everything except "test2"
- `xargs rm -r` pipes the output from previous command to `rm -r` command.

Comment: And with recursive delete of all sub folders
find myfolder/* -type d | grep -v "test2" | xargs rm -rf

Answer (score 1):

Tested with below command and it worked fine

```
find  /home/myfolder -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -iname test2 -exec rm -rvf {} \;
```

Comment: You've run into the same problem as the OP; listing /home/folder on the command-line (without the critical `-mindepth 1`) makes that top directory match all the criteria (it's a directory and it's not named "test2") and so it gets deleted.